# How to inject object into ionic controller from cordova plugin?

Tags: javascript, cordova, push-notification, ionic-framework, onesignal

I'm trying to integrate push notifications into my Ionic/Cordova app. I'm using a service OneSignal for integration. I have successfully set up my iPhone to receive push notifications from OneSignal's web interface.

The next step is to get the pushToken (which OneSignal/Apple uses to send push
notifications to a single device) to populate in my app's ionic
controller so that I can implement application logic and push messages
based on app events.

I installed their (OneSignal's) Cordova plugin and my iPhone registers and it reports the pushToken.  However I cannot pass the pushToken string to any of my controllers for the life of me. How can I do this? Below is my app.js and controller.js.

app.js

```
angular.module('cApp', ['ionic', 'cApp.controllers'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSplashscreen, $rootScope) {

$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true); // Fixes keyboard issue
}

if (window.StatusBar) {
  // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}

/*===========================================================================
http://documentation.onesignal.com/v2.0/docs/phonegap--cordova-sdk-api#init
===========================================================================*/
window.plugins.OneSignal.init("5eb87dse-b458-11e3-ac11-000c2940e62c",
  {googleProjectNumber: "",
    autoRegister: true},
        app.didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack);


window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
    console.log('getIds: ' + JSON.stringify(ids)); // I can see PushToken and UserId in the console.
    $rootScope.pushToken = ids.pushToken;
});

});

console.log($rootScope.pushToken);

})

// Configure Routes....... etc.
```

controller.js

```
.controller('MenuCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicModal, $ionicPlatform) {

console.log($rootScope.pushToken); // It comes back undefined :(
```

Comment: In controller.js can you try adding a delay to the printing of $rootScope.pushToken? The callback does not trigger right away from OneSignal.getIds().

Can you do what you need with the pushToken in app.js? Do you have to have it in your controller.js?

Comment: Thanks for the tips Jkasten. I tried to delay the printing of $rootScope.pushToken and it stuff shows up blank in the console (it's not showing up). As far as being able to do what I need to do in app.js, I don't think so. I essentially need to pass the $rootScope.pushToken to another server.  That process needs to be done in a controller.

Comment: UPDATE: I tried again to delay the printing of $rootScope.pushToken in the 'MenuCtrl' and it does show up in console within the timer in the 'MenuCtrl'.  How can I make it so that I can access the $rootScope.pushToken to pass around my function outside of the $timer? Do I have call $scope.$apply(); or something like that in order to update the scope variable or do something with the digest cycle?  In other works how can I sync up the $rootScope.pushToken with all of the other application variables?  Thank you very much for your initial response. I have gotten much further!

Comment: Instead of calling `$rootScope.pushToken = ids.pushToken;` from app.js can you call a function that is in controller.js with the `$rootScope`? 
Example: `$rootScope.setPushToken(ids.pushToken);`

Comment: I was unable to create a function in the controller & pass ids.pushToken to it.  Things just come up undefined.  However, I was able to pass ids.pushToken to the $rootScope.pushToken & inject it into my controller. The last outstanding issue I'm facing is I'm unable to bind didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack(message, additionalData, isFirstOpen) {}; which is a parameter of window.plugins.OneSignal.init(); to ionic / angular.  When I receive a push msg, I can see it in my console, but I don't know how to capture it to tell ionic to open a different view when someone toggles the notification.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like app.js runs before your controller.js. If this is the case you should be able to do the following;

- To handle when your app is opened from a notification

  - Set a variable on $rootScope in didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack and read it in your controller.
- To handle when your app is running and you get a notification

  - Assign a handler function on $rootScope in your controller and call in your didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack if it exists.

Here is the code implementing these 2 flows:

**app.js:**

```
didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack(message, additionalData, isActive) {
  var notificationObj = {message: message, additionalData: additionalData, isActive: isActive};
  if ($rootScope.notificationReceivedHandler)
    $rootScope.notificationReceivedHandler(notificationObj);
  else
    $rootScope.openedFromNotification = notificationObj;
}
```

**controller.js:**

```
.controller('MenuCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicModal, $ionicPlatform) {
  if ($rootScope.openedFromNotification)
    processNotificationOpened($rootScope.openedFromNotification);
  $rootScope.openedFromNotification = processNotificationOpened;
}

function processNotificationOpened(notificationObj) {
  // Read and process what you need to here.
}
```

NOTE: The code above is not tested.